# Run a given number of the same process concurrently

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

My situation is simple but complex. I am trying to write a program, that needs to execute an external process 1100 times, 4 at a time. I am completely stumped on how to go about this. The application I am writing is a "Windows Form Application", and I am utilizing BackgroundWorker to run the tasks async.

Example, I have a list of 1100 different strings, and I want to run the process 1 time per string, but only 4 at a time, and then move on to the next 4.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why only 4 at a time? Is it due to the processor cores?

Comment: Generally, [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd783747%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) over a sequence of 1100 strings with [`ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) set to 4 should get you started.

Comment: The main application is a WinForms, but what type of application is the worker process? Also, your tags 'multithreading' and 'backgroundworker' apply to concurrent threads, not processes.

Comment: @BasBrekelmans The number 4 is a user input but, I am new to multithreading and I was under the assumption that the number of cores would play a part.

Comment: @nicholas Each thread will run a process and wait for it to exit, parse the output, and utilize that data for later charting.

Comment: What version of C#/.NET are you using?

Comment: This is going to be an in-house application, so the version can be anything up to 4.5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```
private async void CodeOnUiThread()
{
    //do ui stuff before starting
    await ExecuteProcesses();
    //do ui stuff after completing.
}

private async Task ExecuteProcesses() 
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        List<string> myStrings = GetMyStrings(); //or whatever you need
        Parallel.ForEach(myStrings,
            new ParallelOptions()
            {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4
            }, (s) =>
            {
                var process = new Process();
                process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("myProcess.exe", s);
                process.Start();
                process.WaitForExit();

            });
    }); 
}
```

This allows a maximum of 4 threads to run simultaniously, thus not allowing more than 4 processes to execute at the same time.

**Update:**

You can also use `Environment.ProcessorCount` to get the number of cores. However the `Parallel.ForEach` call will handle this correctly by default.

**Update 2**

`Parallel.ForEach` will block the thread currently running. I have updated the code above.

Comment: Huge thanks, I think you have pointed me in the proper direction. And it would be ok I assume to run this code on a background worker to keep my UI responsive?

Comment: Marked as answer as it is definitely what I want, but running it on the UI thread, locks up my form, until the processes have finished.

Comment: Apologies @WilliamRiley, Parallel.ForEach is a blocking call. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

How about this (complete example):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<StringContainer> strContainers = new List<StringContainer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1100; i++)
        {
            strContainers.Add(new StringContainer() { str = "string" + i });
        }

        Parallel.ForEach(
            strContainers,
            new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 },
            x => ProcessString(x));

        foreach (var item in strContainers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.str);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void ProcessString(StringContainer strContainer)
    {
        strContainer.str += "_processed";
    }
}

public class StringContainer
{
    public string str;
}
```